# Оптимальный способ получить 2 одинаковых хеша в разные промежутки времени

Tags: python, математика, псевдокод

Есть сервис, где ко мне приходит пользователь, я генерирую ему хеш и отдаю ему:

```
date_user = hash(round(time.time()/1000)) # Первая дата 
return date_user
```

Потом спустя `N` времени он ко мне приходит (при этом `N < 1000s`, то есть `N` - это время его жизни), я на сервере опять генерирую хеш и сравниваю с хешам пользователя:

```
date_user = round(time.time()/1000)

# Не критично что время жизни возрастает в 2 раза
if date_user == hash(date_2) or date_user == hash(date_2-1):
   return 'ok'
else:
   return 'err'
```

Вопрос в том, возможно исключить ситуации на промежутки где приходиться генерировать 2 хеша?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про JWT(JSON Web Token) в нем вы можете сохранить в json произвольные данные и передать их юзеру(юзер не может их расшифровать)и потом получив обратно просто прочитать их.

Comment: Ну, мне кажетсья это плохой вариант, уж лучше лучше я запишу данные в БД и привяжу их к hash и отдам пользователю, чем буду хранить хоть что-то на стороне клиента в зашифрованном виде, мне почему-то кажется это ужасной практикой

Comment: Ну банки и социальные сети хранят таким образом данные. Если вы применяете готовые библиотке, то вероятность взлома данных будет меньше, чем вероятость взлома сервера.)2. Штука в том что внутри jwt уже встроенно время годности токена, и еще 100500 фич которые вам могут понадабиться...

Comment: Ну, вообще это не особо сложно сделать без готовых lib, но вообще jwt выглядит очень крута по doc, но просто легче хранить эти данные сразу на стороне сервера в БД и все же взлом сервера с внешним firewall и доступом только по 127.0.0.1 ну кране мала даже с расшифровкой данных, да и нет необходимости проверять валидность данный при получении от пользователя. Но повторюсь, вариант с jwt интересен.

Answer (score 1):

Отдавайте пользователю не чистый хеш, а строку состоящую из **хеша** и **метки времени**, которая применялась для генерации хеша.
При принятии данных от пользователя разбивайте строку на хеш и метку времени. Затем проверяйте не истекло ли время. Если не истекло, проверяйте хеш используя пришедшую метку времени.

Comment: Вообще да, даже не думал над тем что-бы отдавать не хеш, но использовать данные пользователя для проверки валидность даных пользователя мне кажется немного не логичным, но если использовать хеш как подпись для метки времени, то идея отличная. 
Спасибо.